# Unable to install fortran based packages in R - "gfortran -m32:not found"

Tags: r, windows-7, fortran, gfortran

I am writing an R package that has Fortran source code.  In short, my problem is when I try to install the package I get the error "gfortran -m32: not found" however, I am able compile my code using gfortran -m32 when I'm not installing the package.

Detailed Version:

I have installed the newest version of R(3.1.1) along with the newest version of Rtools(31) and renamed my path variables accordingly (C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\x64;C:\msys;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin).

For testing purposes, I downloaded the PropClust package from CRAN which has Fortran source code.

When I type "R CMD INSTALL PropClust_1.4.tar.gz" after building it, I get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package 'PropClust' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:202: warning: overriding recipe for target `.m.o'
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:195: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `.m.o'
gfortran -m32   -O3  -mtune=core2 -c  PropClustParallelTrials.f90 -o PropClustParallelTrials.o
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c minWhichMin.c -o minWhichMin.o
gfortran -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o PropClust.dll tmp.def PropClustParallelTrials.o minWhichMin.o -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib  -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/i386 -lR
gfortran -m32: not found
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:202: warning: overriding recipe for target `.m.o'
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:195: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `.m.o'
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/i386/Rterm.exe
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/i386/Rterm.exe
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'PropClust'
* removing 'C:/Users/kamicz/Documents/IsotopeR/PropClust.Rcheck/PropClust'
```

Although it says "gfortran -m32: not found" I have compiled my code in the same window with the same options(gfortran -m32 -O3 -mtne=core2 -c a.f90 -o a.out) with no problems. Has anyone had this problem before?  I am running Windows 7 64-bit if that matters.

Comment: The problem might be the way, how flags are handled by such libraries. E.g. in python's `subprocess` module, the command and each flag have to be a *separate* string. Supplying `gfortran -m32` might be understood as a program with this name, instead of `gfortran` with flag `-m32`. Could you remove the flag (do you need 32bit?)?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem : `R` was invoking `gfortran-4.8` - an unrecognized command on my system - instead of `gfortran`. This problem was fixed upon creating the file `~/.R/Makevars` within my home directory. Here are the contents of  `Makevars` which points to the appropriate `gfortran` installation:

```
F77 = gfortran
FC = gfortran
FLIBS = -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me after doing `brew install gfortran` then substituting my local path (check via `which gfortran`) into the last line above. Thanks