# OS X package installation issue: Can't find gfortran 4.8 to build package

Tags: r, fortran, package

I have an issue on mac os x El Capitan with Xcode 7. I'm using fortran 6.1, downloaded from https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries. I tried degrading to fortran 4.8. but that didn't help me. Following is the error:

> installing *source* package ‘Nepidemic’ ... libs gfortran-4.8  -fPIC
>   -Wall -g -O2  -c  random_epi.f95 -o random_epi.o make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory make: *** [random_epi.o] Error 1 ERROR:
>   compilation failed for package ‘Epidemic’

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Found one similar issue,
 [Can't find gfortran 4.8 to build package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315422/cant-find-gfortran-4-8-to-build-package/37752505#37752505)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following: [Unable to install fortran based packages in R - "gfortran -m32:not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347730/unable-to-install-fortran-based-packages-in-r-gfortran-m32not-found?rq=1)

I installed gfortran 6.1 from https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS

Then, I added the following to the file ~/.R/Makevars within my home directory pointing to my gfortran installation:

```
F77 = gfortran
FC = gfortran
FLIBS = -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how can I add those in  ~/.R/Makevars. I'm very new in this programming world!

Comment: Create a directory in your home directory called `.R`.  With a text editor, create a file called `Makevars` in this new directory.  Paste the text above in this file.

Comment: Still working on my system running:
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

Comment: Thanks.  Mine is not working now.  Removed 6.1 and installed 4.8. Still lots of issues.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me under macOS Sierra (10.12.2), R version 3.3.2 and gfortran 5.4.0 installed from MacPorts.