# R package with Fortran Source Code: how to make “Makevars” file under “pkgname/src/”?

Tags: r, makefile, fortran, gfortran, r-package

Related to the solution of my past question, [OS X package installation issue: Can't find gfortran 4.8 to build package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753941/os-x-package-installation-issue-cant-find-gfortran-4-8-to-build-package/37754162#37754162),
I have the Makevars in ~/.R/. This allows me to build the R package and work locally on my system.

Now I want to make this package portable. I tried moving this Makevars to src folder and got the following error:

```
 * installing *source* package ‘pkgname’ ...
 ** libs
 gfortran-4.8  -fPIC -Wall -g -O2  -c  epidata.f95 -o epidata.o
 make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
 make: *** [epidata.o] Error 1
 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘pkgname’
 * removing ‘/Users/Vineetha/Desktop/pkgname.Rcheck/pkgname’
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran]. Very few people follow [tag:fortran95].

Comment: Why do you use `gfortran-4.8` instead of just `gfortran`? Have you used the answer which you accepted in the other question?

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, the answer was accepted for the other question.  I'm using gfortran 6.1 but the error comes with 4.8. My issue is how I can change the contents in the current  Makevar file to be used in src folder.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that gfortran-4.8 is available on every system.

Comment: In the same way as in the other answer. They look the same to me.

Comment: See the [discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2015-October/011641.html) in the R-Sig-Mac mailing list. Especially this [this reply](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2015-October/011663.html). You cannot just assume that every system has gfortran 4.8; it is not portable.

Comment: @Bhas  I have only gfortran6.1  on my system

Comment: That's the point!!!

Comment: @Vineetha. To be portable use only `gfortran`. Do not specify a specific version. `Vladimir F` put it succinctly and well. The version of gfortran you use doesn't matter as long as you don't use Fortran features that are specific to version 6.1.

Comment: @Bhas  I didn't mention the gfortran version anywhere in the package.  Could you explain a bit more please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I now think that I understand the problem.

You have used the gfortran from the [gfortranbinaries page](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries) on the wiki.

You have adapted your `~/.R/Makevars/` so that the macros `FC`, `F77` and `FLIBS` point to the correct binaries and libraries.

You move that `Makevars` to your package `src` folder to make your package portable. You are assuming that it will be portable. You assume (or hope) that the R package builder will respect your choice of compiler. However it doesn't work that way.

When R builds a package it will always use the compilers that were used for building the R version you are using. You **cannot** override the above macros in a package `Makevars`. Those macros can only be changed in 
a `~/.R/Makevars/`.

The R version you are most likely using was compiled on OS X mavericks with a specially compiled gfortran 4.8.2.; that is what R is complaining about. It can be obtained from [here](https://r.research.att.com/libs). You would have to use the Terminal to unpack the compressed file to the correct place. However you can't just install that version of gfortran because it will partly overwrite your version 6.1. ***So do not do that!***.

You need not worry about using `gfortran 6.1` as you are doing. See page 57 of the (patched) [R installation and administration manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.pdf).

It states that you can and may use the gfortran you are using with a binary version of R obtained from CRAN.

So there is **no need** to move your `~/.R/Makevars/` out of the way.

To check portability of your package you can send it to the [winbuilder](https://win-builder.r-project.org) service. Or use a Linux virtual machine for example.

To keep a package with Fortran source portable don't use any extensions of that compiler and don't use Fortran extensions specific to that version of your compiler.

In short, you don't have to resolve the issue you mentioned. Just write portable code.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Will try your suggestions.

Comment: The Makevar file is not working locally now. I do not know any further changes had happened. I tried upgrading to Sierra too.

Comment: I removed 6.1 and downloaded gfortran 4.8.2. Got another error      gfortran-4.8  -fPIC -Wall -g -O2  -c  test.f95 -o test.o
gfortran-4.8: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘16.0.0. Any idea why?